# Changing from scattermapbox to densitymapbox causes error

Tags: python, plotly, mapbox, plotly-dash

I was looking for a solution to this issue I encountered. There is a question almost similar to mine in plotly community (https://community.plot.ly/t/problem-with-densitymapbox-chart-type/28517), but still haven’t found a resolution. My dropdown menu consists of scattermapbox and densitymapbox as i wanted to juggle between these. However, when changing from scattermapbox to densitymapbox, it results to the image below:

[densitymapbox after scattermapbox format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ua12V.png)
    import dash
    import copy
    import pathlib
    import dash
    import numpy as np
    import math
    import datetime as dt
    import pandas as pd
    from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State, ClientsideFunction
    import dash_core_components as dcc
    import dash_html_components as html
    import dash_table
    import plotly.graph_objs as go

```
# get relative data folder
PATH = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent
DATA_PATH = PATH.joinpath("data").resolve()

external_scripts = [
‘https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-1.39.1.min.js’
]

external_stylesheets = [
‘https://codepen.io/etpinard/pen/wxwPXJ’
]

app = dash.Dash(
    __name__, 
    external_scripts=external_scripts,
    external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets
)

server = app.server

# Load data
df = pd.read_excel("Clean_TR(6.8.19).xlsx")

group_name = df['gname'].unique()

mapbox_access_token = <your token>

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Store(id = 'aggregate_data'),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id = 'map_plot',
            options = [{'label':i, "value":i} for i in ['Scatter', 'Density']],
            value = ['Scatter']
        ),
        dcc.Graph(id = 'mindanao-map')
    ]
)

@app.callback(
    Output('mindanao-map', 'figure'),
    [Input('map_plot', 'value')]
)
def update_map(map_plot):
    if map_plot == "Density":
        maptype = 'densitymapbox'
    else:
        maptype = 'scattermapbox'

    return {
        'data' : [{
                'lat':df['latitude'],
                'lon':df['longitude'],
                'marker':{
                    'color': df['freq'],
                    'size': 8,
                    'opacity': 0.6
                },
                'customdata': df['idno'],
                'type': maptype
        }],
        'layout': {
            'mapbox': {
                'accesstoken': mapbox_access_token,
                'style':"light",
                'center': dict(lon=123.30, lat= 7.50),
                'zoom':'6',
            },
            'hovermode': 'closest',
            'margin': {'l': 0, 'r': 0, 'b': 0, 't': 0}
        }
    }

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

But whenever I swap out the if-else ordering, i.e,

```
if map_plot == "Scatter":
    maptype = 'scattermapbox'
else:
    maptype = 'densitymapbox'
```

it results to density map showing, but scatter will not.
Do I need to separate these two instead of if-else? Any inputs will do. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I believe this is currently a bug in Plotly.js which we should fix.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Plotly.js bug, and I've filed a report here: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/4285

Edit: this bug is fixed in recent versions of Plotly.js and Plotly.py and Dash.